# Stop Chrome autocompleting address by default

Tags: google-chrome, search, autocomplete, address-bar, navigation

I do **not** want to disable autocomplete, I just want to stop the following scenario;

In the address bar type `example` and enter, then `exam` and enter.
For me it searched `example` again! It autocompleted for me when I wanted to actually write `exam`.

[image]

I know all I had to do was backspace the highlighted text, but I see autocomplete as something I should opt-in to, not opt-out of.

I vaguely remember, in the past, it working by showing a drop down with the various autocomplete options as you typed. To select one you actually had to click one/press the down key. But, should you hit enter without doing that it would go to *exactly what you typed*.

I really like autocomplete, but most of the time I mean what I type, and the autocomplete is the lesser user-case. Is there a setting to make it behave as described?

Basically I want it to keep **suggesting** completions for my searches without **autocompleting** it for me (if that makes it clearer).

Answer (score -1):

Turning off Predictions in the Address Bar:

1. Clear browsing history (optional - only do this if you don't want to see matches from your browsing history).
2. Wrench Icon --> Options --> Under the hood --> Privacy --> uncheck "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar"

---

Turning off Form Autofill (aka Autocomplete):

Wrench Icon --> Options --> Personal Stuff --> Autofill --> uncheck "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click"

---

Source: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0DR-pLIVI5g%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: 1- I don't want to destroy its ability to perform autocomplete. 2- This didn't work, unfortunately. 3- That's for forms, i.e. fields *in* the page, not for the address bar (as depicted).

Answer (score -1):

Press `shift-delete` when autocomplete is showing you a match you do not want.

Comment: it's not about the individual matches, it's about matching at all. Hitting shift delete is just as bad (well, worse) than simply hitting backspace, keypress-wise, and the fact it would permanently take away that particular suggestion breaks the last requirement; "I want it to keep suggesting completions"